# PHP GET and POST data with fsockopen

Tags: php, sockets, variables, post, fsockopen

How to get, and post data through the same socket with PHP? I have this code:

```
$fp = fsockopen("ssl://ovi.rdw.nl", 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);
if(!$fp){
    echo $errstr;
}else{
$post_data = 'ctl00$cntMaincol$btnZoeken=Zoeken&ctl00$cntMaincol$txtKenteken=83FHVN';

$out = "GET /Default.aspx HTTP/1.0\r\n";
$out .= "Host: ovi.rdw.nl\r\n";
$out .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
fwrite($fp, $out);

while(!feof($fp)){
    $data = fgets($fp);
    $view_state = getViewState($data);
    if($view_state != ""){
        echo $view_state."<br />";
        break;
    }
}

$post_data = "__VIEWSTATE={$view_state}&".$post_data;

$out = "POST /Default.aspx HTTP/1.0\r\n";
$out .= "Host: ovi.rdw.nl\r\n";
$out .= "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$out .= "Content-length: " . strlen($post_data) . "\r\n";
$out .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
fwrite($fp, $out);
fwrite($fp, $post_data);
while(!feof($fp)){
    echo fgets($fp);
}
}
```

It get's the data right, but the posting it is not going ok. What do i mis?

Answer (score 1):

You're doing a GET and a POST in the same connection, This isn't valid for HTTP/1.0 which you have specified and re-assured via connection: close.  Comment out your get portion and just do the post.

You can get data back with a post, so you don't need to do a get and a post.  Or if you do need to do a get and a post, close the socket, then re-establish the socket again for the post.

Comment: I need to firts do the get to get the $view_state value, otherwise it would be empty. When i re-astablish a new connection the $view_state would be different, so that wouldn't help.

Comment: Then after the GET, close the socket, and open another connection for the POST.  The connection should be getting dropped after your get buffer empties, and your post is ignored.

Comment: Whoops, re-read your statment.  Well, if you must have the same connection you need to switch to http 1.1, and use persistent connections via Connection: Keep-Alive instead of connection: close

Comment: Ok, then i get do the get request firts, flush using fflush, and then do the post?

Answer (score 0):

don't forget to [`fflush()`](http://ca.php.net/fflush)

Comment: it flushes any buffered data through the stream.

Answer (score 0):

Curl is too heavy in some case, to use post_to_host():

```
//GET:
$str_rtn=post_to_host($str_url_target, array(), $arr_cookie, $str_url_referer, $ref_arr_head, 0);

//POST:
$arr_params=array('para1'=>'...', 'para2'=>'...');
$str_rtn=post_to_host($str_url_target, $arr_params, $arr_cookie, $str_url_referer, $ref_arr_head);

//POST with file:
$arr_params=array('para1'=>'...', 'FILE:para2'=>'/tmp/test.jpg', 'para3'=>'...');
$str_rtn=post_to_host($str_url_target, $arr_params, $arr_cookie, $str_url_referer, $ref_arr_head, 2);

//raw POST:
$tmp=array_search('uri', @array_flip(stream_get_meta_data($GLOBALS[mt_rand()]=tmpfile())));
$arr_params=array('para1'=>'...', 'para2'=>'...');
file_put_contents($tmp, json_encode($arr_params));
$arr_params=array($tmp);
$str_rtn=post_to_host($str_url_target, $arr_params, $arr_cookie, $str_url_referer, $ref_arr_head, 3);

//get cookie and merge cookies:
$arr_new_cookie=get_cookies_from_heads($ref_arr_head)+$arr_old_cookie;//don't change the order

//get redirect url:
$str_url_redirect=get_from_heads($ref_arr_head, 'Location');
```

post to host php project location: http://code.google.com/p/post-to-host/